# Highcharts Pie, slice first item in series

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a series of data in a pie chart, ordered from highest to lowest value. I want the pie chart to slice out the first (largest) value. I tried a combination of things with no success. My pie chart code is below.

How do I do this via the initializing of the pie?

```
        $(divID).highcharts({
            credits: false,
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false,
                type: 'pie'
            },
            title: {
                text: chartData.title
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: chartData.subtitle
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        formatter: function () {
                            return Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.round(this.percentage * 100) / 100, 1) + '%';
                        },
                        distance: -30,
                        color: 'black'
                    },
                    showInLegend: true
                }
            },
            noData: {
                enabled: true
            },
            series: [{
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: chartData.seriesData[0]
            }]
        });
```

I tried this after the init, but still the last slice is selected.

```
        $(divID).highcharts.series[0].data[0].slice();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slice the first point on load event - see [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load)

```
chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    events: {
      load: function () {
        this.series[0].data[0].slice();
      }
    }
},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/zmgxtn1m/

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts doesn't order your series, you could get the max then select the data which is the max

```
var chart =  $(divID).highcharts;
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, chart.series[0].data.map(function(v){
    return v.y;
}));
var maxData = chart.series[0].data.filter(function(v){
    if (v.y == max)
    {
        return v.y;
    }
})[0]
```

here is a fiddle that selects the data with the highest values using the stock pie chart http://jsfiddle.net/1zLxnycf/